# Should I always call TcpClient.EndConnect (even when connection fails?)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, webclient, tcpclient

C# has several useful classes for networking tasks such as TcpClient and WebClient. Both have BeginX methods (BeginConnect and BeginGetResponse respectively) that according to MSDN should always be followed by EndX. Both accepts a delegate that is called once the operation is complete.

However, say we fail to establish a connection, and thus calling those methods would throw an exception. Should I still call the respective EndX methods, or should I first check whether the connection was established, and only then call them?

Alternatively, in the following example, should I use OnSocketConnected1 or OnSocketConnected2?

```
static TcpClient m_client;

private static void OnSocketConnected1 (IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
  try
  {
    m_client.EndConnect(asynchronousResult);
  }
  catch { }
}

private static void OnSocketConnected2(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
  if (m_client.Connected)
  {
    try
    {
      m_client.EndConnect(asynchronousResult);
    }
    catch { }
  }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  m_client = new TcpClient();
  m_client.BeginConnect("http://www.example.com", 555, OnSocketConnected, null);
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MSDN Quote, TcpClient.BeginConnect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xw3y33he.aspx)

> The asynchronous BeginConnect
>   operation must be completed by calling
>   the EndConnect method. Typically, the
>   method is invoked by the asyncCallback
>   delegate.

I see no exception to that rule here. And your fields shouldn't matter (read: Version 1, call EndConnect unconditionally, right away).

Comment: Perhaps that's not correct. I got SocketException raised while calling EndConnect() in the callback function with connection failed. It said(I translate it from Chinese, may not be accurate):Do socket operation to network that cannot be connected.

Answer (score 1):

My instinct would say yes, as it would probably allow the framework to **garbage-collect the IAsyncResult object**.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void OnSocketConnected1 (IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
  try
  {
    m_client.EndConnect(asynchronousResult);
  }
  catch { }
}
```

Comment: EndConnect will still throw an exception, if the connection failed to establish

Comment: This seems odd to me. EndConnect is needed to do something meaningful. Why do you suggest doing it as the last thing in the callback method?

Comment: lol, what did I write there?!? will edit my post... thx for the input

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the second version does what you think it does.  Socket.Connect returns information about the most recent IO command.  You won't have a connection until EndConnect completes.

Answer (score 0):

From my own experience, it looks like `socket.EndConnect()` or `socket.Close()` are irrelevant. If you failed to make a connection, the `socket.Dispose` method (which will get called when the socket is destroyed) appears to be trying to disconnect anyway. When I call `Dispose()`, `EndConnect()` or `Close()`, or simply put the socket into a `USING` block, I get the same behaviour - a slow disconnection rather than an instant response. In fact, I haven't found a way to stop this happening even if I wanted it to.

Answer (score 0):

I've just traced a very difficult issue to this same question and concluded that, in my case at least, my issue was caused by not calling EndConnect with the IASyncResult.  The problem was that subsequent connections would be disconnected.  Calling EndConnect correctly resolved the issue.